# Set first column values of csv to variable separate by comma

Tags: bash

Right now I'm doing this:

```
ct=`tail -n +2 $meta | cat | cut -d, -f1 | tr '\n' ','`
```

But the list of values I'm getting in the variable ct are separated by spaces, not commas. I also did this and I got the same result.

```
ct=`tail -n +2 $meta | cat | cut -d, -f1 | paste -s -d,`
```

The values can have spaces.

Input:

The meta variable has a csv file with values like

```
path_document,file_name
/path1/1 2.pdf,what
/path2/21.pdf,how
/path3/325.pdf,who
```

I want ct to have the values of the first column of the file separated by commas like this

```
/path1/1 2.pdf,/path2/21.pdf,/path3/325.pdf
```

but with the commands above I'm getting this

```
/path1/1 2.pdf /path2/21.pdf /path3/325.pdf
```

Comment: Add the text that you are working with and your expected output. Without that, it's nigh impossible to help you.

Comment: Works for me; are you sure you haven't set `$IFS` by mistake?

Comment: @StephenHarris yes that could be it! I was trying to loop over those values so I changed IFS but then the loop is not working

Comment: It sounds like a better construct for your use case _might_ be to keep it as separate lines and and use a while loop.  eg ct=`tail -n +2 $meta | cat | cut -d, -f1` followed by `echo "$ct" | while read entry; do ... done`

Comment: @StephenHarris Yes, thanks for the suggestion, I think that works better